# php driven website as windows executable

Tags: php, windows

Is there any way to get my PHP/SQL driven website to be encapsulated as a windows executable (for FREE)? It doesn't matter if there are extra files as well as the executable, I just want it to be something that I can distribute without people having to install a web server and web browser (I would prefer if the presumably-embedded browser was Chrome, but I know I will probably have to settle for IE).

At the moment the options seem to be Bambalam, exeOutput and XAMPP. Unfortunately I can't use Bambalam since it is immediately destroyed by my virus scanner and I haven't tried XAMPP or exeOutput yet (downloading now).

Does anyone know any other options that I can use entirely from Windows (nothing that I need to run on Unix to produce the executable, etc.)? Thanks.

(Thinking about it a bit more, I could probably rewrite my site to use SQLite and then just use an IE WebBrowser control to load the page locally or something, but an existing solution would be better)

Comment: XAMPP it will just install and configure for you the Apache with php and mysql (and more). So I don't think it's a solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give [Server2Go](http://www.server2go-web.de/) a look. It's a portable webserver bundle that starts the webserver, mysql-server and browser with your page all with the click of one exe-file.

Comment: Sorry for the 18 month delay - this is what I ended up using.